# Divisibility into primes quadruples

Tags: prime-numbers, divisibility, prime-gaps

Reading about quadruples of primes, it is clear that these must have the form $(p,p+2,p+6,p+8)$, ($p>5$).

Consider the first three quadruples:
$\{11, 13, 17, 19\}, \{101, 103, 107, 109\}, \{191, 193, 197, 199\}$ Now let's add each element of each quadruple: $11+13+17+19=60$, for the second quadruple $101+103+107+109=420$ and for tje third quadruple $191+193+197+199=780$.

Note that:

$60|60\Rightarrow  60*1=60$

$60|420\Rightarrow  60*7=420$

$60|780\Rightarrow 60*13=780$

This property seems to hold forever, where does this property come from?  Does the sequence of numbers $1,7,13,...$  have any relationship?

Comment: You may wish to look at https://oeis.org/A112540

Answer (score 1):

Of the $5$ numbers
$$p,\,p+2,\,p+4,\,p+6,\,p+8$$
one must be a multiple of $3$ and one must be a multiple of $5$.

It follows that $3{\,\mid\,}(p+4)$ and $5{\,\mid\,}(p+4)$, so $15{\,\mid\,}(p+4)$, hence
$$
p+(p+2)+(p+6)+(p+8)=4p+16=4(p+4)
$$
is a multiple of $4{\,\cdot\,}15=60$.